# Google navigation dialog box "you're navigating a route "

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an app where I launched several Google maps directions using intent.
Each time I want to launch a new direction the modal dialog box You're navigating a route appears.
How I can get rid of this

Comment: Can you elaborate on it? But I am guessing you have a dialogFragment in your app that you don't know about.